# resize image doesn't work in my codigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

it does not show any error, and do nothing, I can not understand whats wrong with it!

```
    public function resize($path,$filename) {

            $config['source_image']    = $path;
            $config['create_thumb']    = TRUE;
            $config['maintain_ratio']  = TRUE;
            $config['width']           = 75;
            $config['height']          = 50;
            $config['new_image']       = './img/uploads/users/'.$filename . '.jpg';
            $this->load->library('image_lib');
            $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->clear();
            if(!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
                echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
            }
}
```

Comment: before everything in the resize function do `if (!is_file($path)) { exit('bad file'); }` and see if you see the bad file text

Comment: the $path is absolutely a directory and no need to check it out, the problem is something else

Comment: You do realize that `source_image` expects a *file* not just a *directory*:  "Sets the source *image name/path*. The path must be a relative or absolute server path, not a URL."

Comment: Also `$this->image_lib->clear();` should be called before `initialize`

Comment: $file_path = './img/uploads/users/' . $file_name . '.jpg';
        $this->resize($file_path,$email);

Comment: That is how i called the method, and that is a file, not just a filename

Comment: Humor me and put my first suggestion into the code. You have nothing to lose. I only say this because I dont see anything outside of the usual with your code and `image_resize` doesn't just fail quietly without a reason. I'm also not sure if this is the cause but typically when using `new_image` `create_thumb` should be false. So do three things, add the exit code change the clear() location and set create thumb to false. If that does not alleviate the problem post more of the code so it can be replicated.

Comment: I did what you've told, and it showed the error bellow:

Comment: The path to the image is not correct.

Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.

Comment: check your phpinfo() and search for `gd` - your server might not support or have the functions required to process images. also the first message means the file you are trying to process doesn't actually exist. i find it rather strange you received both errors rather than just one as each of those errors stops the script from getting to the next one as it returns false in the core lib. weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are calling clear method before resize method, it clears all settings try this method, i have tested with same directory structure it works fine

```
public function resize($path, $filename)
    {
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $path;
        $config['create_thumb'] = true;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = true;
        $config['width'] = 75;
        $config['height'] = 50;
        $config['new_image'] = './img/uploads/users/' . $filename . '.jpg';
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        // $this->image_lib->clear();
        if (!$this->image_lib->resize()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
    }
```

Comment: part of the problem but not the whole picture. see comments.